# What are the number of swaps required in selection sort for each case?

Tags: sorting, swap, selection-sort

I believe that selection sort has the following behavior:

**Best case**: No swaps required as all elements are properly arranged

**Worst case**: n-1 swaps required i.e a swap required for each pass and there are n-1 passes as we know where n is number of elements in array

**Average case**: Not able to find out this. What is the procedure for finding it out?

Is the above information correct?

This says time complexity of swaps in best case is O(n) 
http://ocw.utm.my/file.php/31/Module/ocwChp5SelectionSort.pdf

Comment: the link is broken. Can you update it?

Answer (score 6):

Each iteration of selection sort consists of scanning across the array, finding the minimum element that hasn't already been placed yet, then swapping it to the appropriate position. In a naive implementation of selection sort, this means that there will always be n - 1 swaps made regardless of distribution of elements in the input array.

If you want to minimize the number of swaps, though, you can implement selection sort so that it doesn't perform a swap in the case where the element to be moved is already in the right place. If you add in this restriction, then you're correct that zero swaps would be made in the best case. (I'm not sure whether it's worthwhile to modify selection sort this way, since swaps are pretty fast in most cases).

Really, it depends on the implementation. You could potentially have a weird implementation of selection sort that constantly swaps the candidate minimum element to its tentative final spot on each iteration, which would dramatically increase the number of swaps in the worst case. I'm not sure why you'd do this, though. It's little details like this that accounts for why your explanation seems at odds with what you've found online - depending on how the code is put together, the number of swaps can be different.

Answer (score 2):

The best case and worst case running time of selection sort are n^2. This is because regardless of how the elements are initially arranged, on the i iteration of the main for loop, the algorithm always inspects each of the remaining n-i elements to find the smallest one remaining.

Selection sort is the algorithm which takes minimum number of swaps, and in the best case it takes ZERO (0) swaps, when the input is in the sorted array like 1,2,3,4. But the more pertinent question is what is the worst case of number of swaps in selection sort? And for which input does it occur?

Answer: Worst case of number of swaps is n-1. But it does not occur for the just the oppositely ordered input, rather the oppositely ordered input like 6,5,3,2,1 does not take the worst number of swaps rather it takes n/2 swaps. So what is really the input for which the number of swaps takes N-1 swaps, if you analyse a bit more you’ll see that the worst case occurs for “SINE WAVE KIND OF AN INPUT”.  That is alternatively increasing and decreasing input, same as the crest and trough.

7 6 8 5 9 4 10 3 - input of eight (8) elements will therefore require 7 swaps

3 6 8 5 9 4 10 7               (1)

3 4 8 5 9 6 10 7               (2)

3 4 5 8 9 6 10 7               (3)

3 4 5 6 9 8 10 7               (4)

3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9               (5)

3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9               (6)

3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10             (7)

Hence proved that the worst case of number of swaps in selection sort is  n-1, best case is 0, and average is (n-1)/2 swaps.

Comment: You're right in pointing out that a reversed-ordered input does not lead to the worst-case number of swaps.  The example you showed leads to a worst-case, but not all alternating inputs will.  Check this: 2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7.  On the other hand, non-alternating inputs such as: 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 also lead to a worst-case.